# Spring Boot: Why do transitive starter dependencies not upgrade to given version?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-starter

My pom.xml looks (in parts) like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.8</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Running `mvn dependency:tree` outputs the following (excerpt):

```
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.8:compile
```

Why is `spring-boot:jar` not upgrading to 2.7.8 as well? That is the version explicitly declared in the starter jar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-boot-starter-parent` includes dependency management for all of Spring Boot's modules as well as numerous third-party dependencies. For reference, they are [listed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.8/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) in Spring Boot's documentation.

When you declare a dependency with a version, it overrides this dependency management but only for this one dependency, not for any of its transitive dependencies. This is Maven's standard behavior.

Generally speaking, you should avoid declaring a version for a dependency that's covered by dependency management. Doing so creates a risk that you will end up with a mixture of versions. In this case, I would recommend upgrading `spring-boot-starter-parent` to `2.7.8` and leaving all of your `org.springframework.boot` dependencies without a version.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect (and check...) that even Spring versions are declared in the BOM. I find it confusing that a Starter contains versions which are not honored. But then I guess it makes sense in cases where you don't use the Parent-POM.